# How can I format a txt file in python so that extra paragraph lines are removed as well as extra blank spaces?

Tags: python

I'm trying to format a file similar to this: (random.txt)

```
        Hi,    im trying   to format  a new txt document so
that extra     spaces between    words   and paragraphs   are only 1.



   This should make     this txt document look like:
```

This is how it should look below: (randomoutput.txt)

```
Hi, I'm trying to format a new txt document so
that extra spaces between words and paragraphs are only 1.

This should make this txt document look like:
```

So far the code I've managed to make has only removed the spaces, but I'm having trouble making it recognize where a new paragraph starts so that it doesn't remove the blank lines between paragraphs. This is what I have so far.

```
def removespaces(input, output):
    ivar = open(input, 'r')
    ovar = open(output, 'w')
    n = ivar.read()
    ovar.write(' '.join(n.split()))
    ivar.close()
    ovar.close()
```

Edit:

I've also found a way to create spaces between paragraphs, but right now it just takes every line break and creates a space between the old line and new line using:

```
m = ivar.readlines()
m[:] = [i for i in m if i != '\n']
ovar.write('\n'.join(m))
```

Comment: +1 for a clear question with a precise problem statement, sample input and expected output and showing reasonable self-effort.  I don't see this kind of (first!) questions very often, these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should process the input line-by line.  Not only will this make your program simpler but also more easy on the system's memory.

The logic for normalizing horizontal white space in a line stays the same (split words and join with a single space).

What you'll need to do for the paragraphs is test whether `line.strip()` is empty (just use it as a boolean expression) and keep a flag whether the previous line was empty too.  You simply throw away the empty lines but if you encounter a non-empty line and the flag is set, print a single empty line before it.

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as istr:
    new_par = False
    for line in istr:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:  # blank
            new_par = True
            continue
        if new_par:
            print()  # print a single blank line
        print(' '.join(line.split()))
        new_par = False
```

If you want to suppress blank lines at the top of the file, you'll need an extra flag that you set only after encountering the first non-blank line.

If you want to go more fancy, have a look at the [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) module but be aware that is has (or, at least, used to have, from what I can say) some bad worst-case performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is that you want to turn any sequence of 2 or more `\n` into exactly 2 `\n` characters. This is hard to write with just `split` and `join`—but it's dead simple to write with [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
n = re.sub(r'\n\n+', r'\n\n', n)
```

If you want lines with nothing but spaces to be treated as blank lines, do this *after* stripping spaces; if you want them to be treated as non-blank, do it *before*.

You probably also want to change your space-stripping code to use `split(' ')` rather than just `split()`, so it doesn't screw up newlines. (You could also use `re.sub` for that as well, but it isn't really necessary, because turning 1 or more spaces into exactly 1 *isn't* hard to write with `split` and `join`.)

---

Alternatively, you could just go line by line, and keep track of the last line (either with an explicit variable inside the loop, or by writing a simple adjacent_pairs iterator, like `i1, i2 = tee(ivar); next(i2); return zip_longest(i1, i2, fillvalue='')`) and if the current line and the previous line are both blank, don't write the current line.

Answer (score 0):

split without Argument will cut your string at each occurence if a whitespace ( space, tab, new line,...). 
Write
    n.split(" ")
and it will only split at spaces.
Instead of writing the output to a file, put it Ingo a New variable, and repeat the step again, this time with

```
m.split("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's see, what exactly is the problem...
You cannot have 1+ consecutive spaces or 2+ consecutive newlines.

You know how to handle 1+ spaces. 
That approach won't work on 2+ newlines as there are 3 possible situations:
  - 1 newline
  - 2 newlines
  - 2+ newlines

Great so.. How do you solve this then?
There are many solutions. I'll list 3 of them.

1. Regex based.
   This problem is very easy to solve iff<sup>1</sup> you know how to use regex...
   So, here's the code:

   ```
   s = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', r'\n\n', in_file.read())
   ```

   If you have memory constraints, this is not the best way as we read the entire file into the momory.
2. While loop based.
   This code is really self-explainatory, but I wrote this line anyway...

   ```
   s = in_file.read()
   while "\n\n\n" in s:
       s = s.replace("\n\n\n", "\n\n")
   ```

   Again, you have memory constraints, we still read the entire file into the momory.
3. State based.
   Another way to approach this problem is line-by-line. By keeping track whether the last line we encountered was blank, we can decide what to do.

   ```
   was_last_line_blank = False
   for line in in_file:
       # Uncomment if you consider lines with only spaces blank
       # line = line.strip()

       if not line:
           was_last_line_blank = True
           continue
       if not was_last_line_blank:
           # Add a new line to output file
           out_file.write("\n")
       # Write contents of `line` in file
       out_file.write(line)

       was_last_line_blank = False
   ```

Now, 2 of them need you to load the entire file into memory, the other one is fairly more complicated. My point is: All these work but since there is a small difference in ow they work, what they need on the system varies...

<sup>1</sup> The "iff" is intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to take lines that are non-empty (so `line.strip()` returns empty string, which is a `False` in boolean context). You can do this using list/generator comprehension on result of `str.splitlines()`, with `if` clause to filterout empty lines.

Then for each line you want to ensure, that all words are separated by single space - for this you can use `' '.join()` on result of `str.split()`.

So this should do the job for you:

```
compressed = '\n'.join(
    ' '.join(line.split()) for line in txt.splitlines() 
        if line.strip() 
    )
```

or you can use `filter` and `map` with helper function to make it maybe more readable:

```
def squash_line(line):
    return ' '.join(line.split())

non_empty_lines = filter(str.strip, txt.splitlines())
compressed = '\n'.join(map(squash_line, non_empty_lines))
```

Answer (score -1):

To fix the paragraph issue:

```
import re
data = open("data.txt").read()

result = re.sub("[\n]+", "\n\n", data)
print(result)
```